# Creating multiple Instances of Custom Class in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, ppm

Basically what title says. I have a Custom named class Color with this constructor:

```
Color(component_t r, component_t g, component_t b) : r(r), g(g), b(b) {

    }
```

The Class "Image" i'm working on has already a protected value of: Color* buffer
I am trying to fill this buffer with instances of the Color class with data from another float* array.This is my code:

```
    Color* buffer = new Color[width*height];

    float* r = new float[width*height];
    float* g = new float[width*height];
    float* b = new float[width*height];

    int i = 0;

    do {
        r[i] = buff[i];
        i++;
        g[i] = buff[i];
        i++;
        b[i] = buff[i];
        i++;
    } while (i < width*height);

    for (int k = 0; k < width*height; k++) {


        buffer[k] = new Color(r[k], g[k], b[k]);
    }
```

However in the 'buffer[k]=new Color(r[k],g[k],b[k])' line inside the for loop its giving me 'no operator "=" matches these operands, operand types are: Color=Color*'

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Other than using raw pointers? ;)    {use smart pointers when you can; or std::vector for what you're doing!!}

Comment: `buffer[k]`is of type Color, as the error messages says. Why do ypu use new at all?

Comment: `g[i] = buff[i];`? Don't you think you need two different indexes? You assign a value to r[0], g[1], b[2].

Comment: Using pointers and new, not using std::vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already created all the `Color`s here:

```
Color* buffer = new Color[width*height];
```

To just change the value of a `buffer` member you can do

```
buffer[k] = Color(r[k], g[k], b[k]);
```

No need to allocate a new `Color`, you already did that before.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that you could do that does something similar:
It's not perfect; as there's a copy of the color object; (but this could be removed too if you wanted to) but it's an attempt to show you what using a vector could do to your code.

```
std::vector<Color> buffer;
buffer.reserve(width*height);

int i = 0;

do {
    float r = buff[i++];
    float g = buff[i++];
    float b = buff[i++]
    buffer.push_back(Color(r,g,b));
} while (i < width*height);
```

Comment: It would be better to use `reserve(width*height);` and `push_back(Color(r,g,b));`

Answer (score 0):

Your `buffer` contains `Color`'s not `Color*`'s.

The following should work:

```
Color** buffer = new Color*[width*height];
```